# Reading enum with hexademinal

Tags: vb.net

Hi can someone give me a little help, this is my Enum code

```
    Enum _WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER
    WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_FIREWALL = &H1
    WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_AUTOUPDATE_SETTINGS = &H2
    WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_ANTIVIRUS = &H4
    WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_ANTISPYWARE = &H8
    WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_INTERNET_SETTINGS = &H16
    WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL = &H32
    WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_SERVICE = &H64
    WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_NONE = &H0
End Enum
    Enum _WSC_SCANNER_SETTINGS
    SCANNER_UNKNOWN = &H1
    SCANNER_RUNNING = &H16
End Enum
Enum _WSC_UPTODATE
    up_To_Date = &H0
    too_Old = &H10
End Enum
```

So I heve this Hexadecimal value: 61100 that in Binary is: 1100001000100000000, and I want that my output be

WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_ANTIVIRUS + WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_AUTOUPDATE_SETTINGS + ???? + up_To_Date

Until now I only have this but it doesn't do what I want

```
        Dim _security As _WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER = hex.Substring(0, 2)
        Dim _scanner As _WSC_SCANNER_SETTINGS = hex.Substring(2, 2)
        Dim _uptodate As _WSC_UPTODATE = hex.Substring(4, 2)

        Console.WriteLine("_security={0}, _scanner={1}, _uptodate={2}",
                          _security,
                          _scanner,
                          _uptodate
                          )
```

I will appreciate the hints.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks. Do you now how to resolve the part of ????(if don't find any value)?

Comment: Not so sure what ??? is supposed to mean, it is questionable.   Maybe you shouldn't skip WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_ALL, it is meant to be useful in an `And` expression to mask out the bits that have a documented meaning.

Comment: It would be much better to test actual number than a string. Even if you decide to use a string, your substring won't work since the number isn't 61100 but 061100.

Answer (score 0):

If you are designing an enum that is meant to represent flags, individual bits, the items in the enum should be powers of two, hex 16 is three bits.  I created this enum as a template so I wouldn't have to do a lot of typing.  Just change the names.

```
<FlagsAttribute()> _
Public Enum bit As Integer
    none = 0
    s0 = 1 << 0
    s1 = 1 << 1
    s2 = 1 << 2
    s3 = 1 << 3
    s4 = 1 << 4
    s5 = 1 << 5
    s6 = 1 << 6
    s7 = 1 << 7
    s8 = 1 << 8
    s9 = 1 << 9
    s10 = 1 << 10
    s11 = 1 << 11
    s12 = 1 << 12
    s13 = 1 << 13
    s14 = 1 << 14
    s15 = 1 << 15
    s16 = 1 << 16
    s17 = 1 << 17
    s18 = 1 << 18
    s19 = 1 << 19
    s20 = 1 << 20
    s21 = 1 << 21
    s22 = 1 << 22
    s23 = 1 << 23
    s24 = 1 << 24
    s25 = 1 << 25
    s26 = 1 << 26
    s27 = 1 << 27
    s28 = 1 << 28
    s29 = 1 << 29
    s30 = 1 << 30
    all = -1
End Enum
```

Normally I comment out unused items, but leave them.